# Swift .append to array not working

Tags: arrays, swift, google-maps, google-api

I am wanting to add every place.name that comes out of the Google API current place function to my array `suggestedLocations`. When I print the array below it always comes out empty.

My aim is to have an array that lists local places. What am I missing?

```
class AddPersonVC: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var firstLocationNameBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var secondLocationNameBtn: UIButton!

var manager = CLLocationManager()

var updateCount = 0
var zoomLevel = 200
var suggestedLocations = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    manager.delegate = self

    // Users current location
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else {
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    // Find all local places
    let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()
    placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoodList, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
            for likelihood in placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods {
                let place = likelihood.place
                suggestedLocations.append(place.name)
                print("Current Place name \(place.name) at likelihood \(likelihood.likelihood)")
                //print("Current Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
                //print("Current Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
                //print("Current PlaceID \(place.placeID)")
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: You are probably printing the contents of the array before the ***asynchronous*** data request even has finished.

Comment: Show where you print it.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks for the advice. What can I do to fix this? The `print` displays the list in the debug log but the array appears blank when I try and print the array immediately below the final brackets but still within ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, your `print` for `array` is below the final brackets but still within the `viewDidLoad`. This is the reason why it is empty, the `placesClient.currentPlace` have not finish running because it is a block method.

You should be calling a print function to show the latest completion array. Try updating the code with this:

```
//remain the above code as it is
    if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
        for likelihood in placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods {
            let place = likelihood.place
            suggestedLocations.append(place.name)
            print("Current Place name \(place.name) at likelihood \(likelihood.likelihood)")
            //print("Current Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
            //print("Current Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
            //print("Current PlaceID \(place.placeID)")
        }
    self.printArray()  //Add a function call on what you want to do with the array here.
    }
})

func printArray() {
    print(suggestedLocations)
}
```

This is just a example to show you how to get a print array. If you are trying to reload a `tableView`, maybe you can call `self.tableView.reloadData()` here as well.